# CSS / jQuery - resize nested container width

Tags: jquery, css

Ok, I've seen a number of similar questions but none of them exactly relate. I'm not confused with the logic, but the actual rendered width of an object is being returned significantly larger than it's width on the screen.

I have a div with a nested ul tag I use for a dropdown (CSS-based). I'm trying to center the dropdown by applying half of the difference of the width of the dropdown menu and it's parent div as a padding-left CSS property.

Here's the code I have:

```
    function resizeNavBar() {
        $("#dropdown").css('padding-left', ((($("#dropdowncontainer").width() - $("#dropdown").width()) / 2) + 'px'));
    }
```

I tried setting the dropdown's margin-right, margin-left to auto and setting the width as a percentage of the parent to center that way to no avail. My problem is the container's width is returning 1186 while the ul is returning 1146, when it's probably more like 900-ish. I never set the width of the dropdown anywhere. Any ideas as to why this is returning such an off number?

Also, it doesn't set the padding-left at all unless I set the width of the dropdown list, but I'm trying to make it dynamic, so why would I do that? That's what I'm trying to get around.

The CSS:

```
#dropdowncontainer
{
clear:both;
height: 28px;
}

#dropdown /* Remove bullets and initialize styling */
{
list-style:none;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

#dropdown li /* All tabs */
{
float:left;
padding-right:0px;
position:relative;
}

#dropdown a /* Tabs with links */
{
display:block;
padding:5px;
color:#FFFFFF; /* Black */
background-color: #D5252B;
text-decoration:none;
}

#dropdown span /* Tabs with links */
{
display:block;
padding:3px;
color:#FFFFFF; /* Black */
background-color: #D5252B;
text-decoration:none;
}

#dropdown ul /* Drop down tabs */
{
background:rgba(255,255,255,0); /* set the background to transparent */
list-style:none;
position:absolute;
left:-11337px; /* Pushes content of dropdown lists off screen until... */
}

#dropdown ul li /* Drop down tabs */
{
padding-top:0px;
float:none;
white-space:nowrap;
}

#dropdown li:hover ul /* Collective set of drop down tabs */
{
left:0; /* ... the user hovers on the link so we pull the content back */
}
```

The HTML:

```
    <div style="width:100%;float: left; height: 40px;">
      <div id="dropdowncontainer">
        <ul id="dropdown">
        <li>Title1<ul>
            <li>item1</li>
            <li>item2</li>
        </ul></li>
            <li>Title2<ul>
            <li>item3</li>
            <li>item4</li>
        </ul></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Firstly, you can't use css(' and hyphenate, it would have to be css(paddingLeft, if you want to do it this way, you must use .css({ }); and include our curly brackets !

Comment: The `<ul>` is probably filling the container, try floating it or `display: inline-block`. What does `$dropdown.outerWidth()` return? Plus I would use negative margins to center instead of padding. Check this script http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/RMsSh/

Comment: @Ohgodwhy That's not true. "Also, jQuery can equally interpret the CSS and DOM formatting of multiple-word properties. For example, jQuery understands and returns the correct value for both .css('background-color') **and** .css('backgroundColor')". See http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: You are correct. I had it mixed up with changing multiple CSS properties. I stand corrected.

Comment: The outerWidth is returning 1186. The width is returning 1146. And with TJ's code below it sets the padding-left to 20px (After I added the missing parenthesis)

Comment: @rjcup3 Could you perhaps put your code in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)? It would make testing a bit easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code. I haven't tested it but it should work:

```
function resizeNavBar() {
    $("#dropdown").css('padding-left', function () {
        return Math.floor($("#dropdowncontainer").width() - $("#dropdown").width()) / 2) + 'px';
    });
}
```

Comment: I mean it does what you want it to, but it doesn't fix the fact that the element's width is returning 1146

Comment: @rjcup3: I'm flattered, but why is my answer suddenly correct? Could you perhaps explain what you did in order to solve your issue?

Comment: I stripped the CSS down a little, but I've never used fiddle before, how do I debug it?

Comment: It isn't, I just didn't want to leave the thread dead. Plus at least you'll get the rep for helping me out.

Comment: If the answer wasn't the correct answer please don't accept it. Just upvote it by pressing the large arrows in the margin. This helps others find it easier and will make the answer more correct! :) Thanks!

Comment: @rjcup3 : I'm thinking that you could probably solve this without javascript. You want to center your <ul>. Have a look at this: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/beautiful-css-centered-menus-no-hacks-full-cross-browser-support

Comment: Yeah, that totally worked, thanks a ton. I still don't know why the returned value was so off...